# Color code process ID in logcat - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I find it hard to follow logs for multithreaded apps. Most of the time it doesn't matter, but currently it does.

I found myself manually coloring thread IDs in some pasted logs in OneNote. Obviously this isn't ideal.

Does anyone know of a simple way to color code thread ID in Android Studio's log cat output?

If not, bonus points for some tool i can paste logs into and it'll color code stuff for me.

Something like the below

[image]